# request permission without Method Channel

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to request WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.
I added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

I know how to request runtime permission in Java [request permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

The same I want to achieve in Dart without using Method Channel and invoking the Java code.
I searched but did not find a way.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. Such information is available *only* with `Method Channel`.

Answer (score 1):

Now, [simple_permissions](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/simple_permissions) plugin is available. It is new but easy to use.